# Some hard drive partition does not shows after formatting with new OS

Tags: windows-8.1

I have windows 8.1. After formatting my C drive and installation of OS my two hard drive partition doesnt show. I have look at disk management it shows but on right click on partition it only shows delete volume option. I want my drive back without lose of my data. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are **two possible** reasons for the event you are mentioning.

1. Those two partitions are not being recognized my Windows. Did you had any other previous OS prior to installing Windows. If this case is true, Windows cant read any data on the partition because it was created in another OS which Windows do not recognizes. However, if you had Linux firstly, you can download **Paragon EXT** and then you can view the *data* on that partition. You may also try **Paragon HFS** if the first one didn't worked for you.
2. Second possibility could be that you Partitions have got corrupted. To recover that Data you can download **EaseUS Hard Disk Recovery Tool** that can help you recover your data on those two partitions. Once done, you can **delete those two partitions** making them available for future data storage.

### Download Links for the Software

**Paragon EXT**    http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/

**Paragon HFS** http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/ (Trial Software)

**EaseUS Partition Recovery** http://www.easeus.com/resource/hard-disk-data-recovery.htm

Comment: Maybe adding some links would be a lot more useful, +1 for addressing some possible issues.

Comment: I had installed Ubuntu previous. Now I thinks this happens because of Ubuntu installation. I will try this one also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the information provided in your question, I'm not sure if this answer can comprehensively resolve your situation; regardless Microsoft has posted a *Troubleshooting Disk Management* guide which can be found by clicking [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771775.aspx#BKMK_2)

**If the file system your volume uses is not supported in Windows, then it will not function in Windows without third-party support in the form of drivers and/or software. A list of Windows-supported file systems can be found by clicking [here](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/und_fs.php#windows)**.

---

From what I garner, it seems that you need to assign a **Drive Letter** to mount your **Volumes**.

## Mounting a Volume in Windows:

1. Open Disk Management (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>K</kbd> to open it from the quick-access menu or <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `diskmgmt.msc` in the run console).
2. Find and right-click the volume you would like to mount.
3. Click `Change Drive Letter and Paths...` from the context menu.
4. Click `Add...`
5. Click the drop-down box and select the drive letter you would like to assign the volume.
6. Verify the volume is mounted by pressing <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and typing your newly minted volume path into *Windows Search* (for instance `C:` would bring you to your C volume).

You can find a procedure guided with pictures [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/82994-drive-letter-add-change-remove-windows.html).

Update: I suggest **rescanning** your **disks**, and proceeding to mount the **Volumes** again if necessary. It is

## Update Disk Information in Windows:

1. Open the Command Prompt (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> to open it from the quick-access menu or <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd` in the run console).
2. If you need to click `OK` to to the Administrator prompt.
3. In Administrator:...cmd.exe type `diskpart`.
4. Now that you are in the diskpart application (in your cmd.exe window) type `rescan`.
5. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.
6. Scroll down to see if your volumes are mounted.

Microsoft also has a guide on how to do this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1e48a29-40ef-458a-90f3-eadcf37c075f#BKMK_WINUI).

Comment: Thank for your kind answer but Cant assign a drive letter. This option is deactivate

Comment: Hey Mrunal, thanks for the promptness of your reply. What is the status of the volume(s) you are trying to access in Disk Management? Does it say *Not Initialized*?Or *Unreadable*?

Comment: Its unreadable. Its does not show drives filesystem. I think drive file system is change from ntfs to something else.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, and to expand *cody*'s answer you may want to check your partition scheme and know wether or not your data is, in fact, present. I recommend you use a proper tool to manage partitions and filesystems, like [GParted](http://gparted.org/).

The link provided offers an standalone, bootable ISO file that you can burn and run on your computer. Once in the app, you can see the state and filesystem type of your partitions. If your partitions are listed as blank, raw or unformatted space, it's most likely that they got corrupt, or either you should be able to see their filesystem type and most likely mount them to backup your data.

The advantages of using GParted are:

1. It's a bootable software, so your filesystems are not in use while you perform any operations.
2. It's linux-based, so you don't have to worry about file permissions and windows privileges.

It's usage is pretty straightforward and simple, but you may need to have some knowledge about linux filesystems, but anyway, you can find more information about its usage on it's [online help pages](http://gparted.org/help.php).

Comment: Thanks arielnmz. I will try this method n will rate the answer if it works

Comment: GParted: your best friend at ground zero.